# MySQL left outer join is slow

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

hoping to get some help with this query, I've worked at it for a while now and can't get it any faster:

```
SELECT date, count(id) as 'visits' FROM dates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN visits 
ON (dates.date = DATE(visits.start) and account_id = 40 ) 
WHERE date >= '2010-12-13' AND date <= '2011-1-13' 
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC
```

That query takes about 8 seconds to run. I've added indexes on dates.date, visits.start, visits.account_id and visits.start+visits.account_id and can't get it to run any faster.

Table structure (only showing relevant columns in visit table):

```
create table visits (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `start` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `end` DATETIME NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `dates` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

dates table contains all days from 2010-1-1 to 2020-1-1 (~3k rows). visits table contains about 400k rows dating from 2010-6-1 to yesterday. I'm using the date table so the join will return 0 visits for days there were no visits.

Results I want for reference:

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | visits |
+------------+--------+
| 2010-12-13 |    301 |
| 2010-12-14 |    356 |
| 2010-12-15 |    423 |
| 2010-12-16 |    332 |
| 2010-12-17 |    346 |
| 2010-12-18 |    226 |
| 2010-12-19 |    213 |
| 2010-12-20 |    311 |
| 2010-12-21 |    273 |
| 2010-12-22 |    286 |
| 2010-12-23 |    241 |
| 2010-12-24 |    149 |
| 2010-12-25 |    102 |
| 2010-12-26 |    174 |
| 2010-12-27 |    258 |
| 2010-12-28 |    348 |
| 2010-12-29 |    392 |
| 2010-12-30 |    395 |
| 2010-12-31 |    278 |
| 2011-01-01 |    241 |
| 2011-01-02 |    295 |
| 2011-01-03 |    369 |
| 2011-01-04 |    438 |
| 2011-01-05 |    393 |
| 2011-01-06 |    368 |
| 2011-01-07 |    435 |
| 2011-01-08 |    313 |
| 2011-01-09 |    250 |
| 2011-01-10 |    345 |
| 2011-01-11 |    387 |
| 2011-01-12 |      0 |
| 2011-01-13 |      0 |
+------------+--------+
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: look up `explain` and `explain extended` in the mysql manual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ON (dates.date = DATE(visits.start) and account_id = 40 )
```

Because you are using the `DATE` function on `visits.start`, MySQL is unable to use an index for the join.

Probably the best solution would be to add a `start_date` and `end_date` column to the `dates` table and index those columns.  So for a row with a date of 2011-01-01, the start date would be 2011-01-01 00:00:00 and the end date would be 2011-01-01 23:59:59.

Then you can join directly to the dates table like so:

```
SELECT date, count(id) as 'visits' FROM dates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN visits 
ON (visits.start BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date and account_id = 40 ) 
WHERE date >= '2010-12-13' AND date <= '2011-1-13' 
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC
```

Another option would be to store the date and time parts separately on the visits table, and join using just the date part.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I added a `start_date` column to the visits table and an index on it. Down to 300ms!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is mainly slow because of the DATE() function. You could add a date column to Visits that stores the whole date and write a trigger to automatically update it when a Visit is inserted or its datetime is updated. That will allow MySQL to make better use of the indexes that are used in the join.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that: outer join on the result of select from eumiro?

```
SELECT date, v.visits as 'visits' FROM dates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DATE(start) as dt, count(id) as 'visits'
FROM visits 
WHERE account_id = 40
AND date BETWEEN '2010-12-13' AND '2011-01-13' 
GROUP BY DATE(start)
ORDER BY 1)
v
ON (dates.date = v.dt ) 
WHERE date >= '2010-12-13' AND date <= '2011-1-13'
```

Edit: edited SQL
Edit: another option - inline select, something like that:

```
SELECT date, (select count(*)  as 'visits' 
FROM  from visits 
where date = DATE(visits.start) and account_id = 40 ) 
) from dates
WHERE date >= '2010-12-13' AND date <= '2011-1-13' 
ORDER BY date ASC
```